# How to connect to different data bases in One DB server but with different instances?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, linked-server

How can I connect to different databases in one Db server but with different instances?
Can I use this statement: `db2.tbl_1.city`?

Comment: you're talking about connecting to different DB from a script (php script for example) ?

Comment: yes different DBS but in local server with different instances. I'm working with asp.net c#. but I want to do it with sql server

Answer (score 0):

You have to use multiple connections: one per instance. A.k.a. each connection is for exactly one instance. Instances are *not* aware of each other which is what'd you'd expect of course

Inside any instance, you'd use the 3 part object names as you did above.

Comment: So is it better using linked server or different connection strings through my Asp.net c# web application. I wanna insert same data in different data bases

Comment: I said use multiple connections. This isn't a correct use of linked servers.